# Error importing File in Blackberry Desktop Software

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have developed an application for Blackberry and am trying to import the cod file into my device using BlackBerry Desktop Manager. I try to import the .COD file. The application was installed earlier on this BlackBerry. When I try to use the Import option I get the error message saying -

> "There was an error importing files. No additional applications can
>   be found. Your file might contain applications that already exist in
>   the application list, are not compatible for your device, or have
>   errors."

Comment: Did you try **first** deleting the old application from your device, and **then** installing it with the BlackBerry Desktop Manager?

Comment: @Nate, removing previously installed app will erase all previously entered data and should be done with precaution.

Comment: What version of RIM OS have you installed on your device? And what version of SDK did you use to compile your cod file? Please note that RIM OS Version must be bigger or equal to the RIM Java SDK version.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov, agreed.  I guess I was assuming this was just a development application still in testing, but you're right.  If the device contains app data that can't be recreated, deleting the app might delete important data.  Good catch.

Comment: Does your new version of the application have a different version number to the one previously imported into the Desktop Manager?

Comment: I was not given any option to delete the software using Blackberry Desktop Manager. I uninstalled it and tried to load the .cod file back in, but was not successful in doing it. Will upload the screen shots if you want me to tomorrow. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Version filed in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml and then signed the deploy-able. Don't get the message any more.